# find row in ruby array

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have a mysql query that returns this type of data:

```
{"id"=>1, "serviceCode"=>"1D00", "price"=>9.19}
{"id"=>2, "serviceCode"=>"1D01", "price"=>9.65}
```

I need to return the `id` field based on a match of the `serviceCode`.

i.e. I need a method like this

```
def findID(serviceCode)
    find the row that has the service code and return the ID
end
```

I was thinking of having a `serviceCodes.each do |row|` method and loop through and essentially go

```
if row == serviceCode 
  return row['id']
end
```

is there a faster / easier way?

Comment: Change the query to return the proper data. That's even faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method [`Enumerable#find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-find):

```
service_codes = [
  {"id"=>1, "serviceCode"=>"1D00", "price"=>9.19},
  {"id"=>2, "serviceCode"=>"1D01", "price"=>9.65}
]

service_codes.find { |row| row['serviceCode'] == '1D00' }
# => {"id"=>1, "serviceCode"=>"1D00", "price"=>9.19}
```

Comment: Enumerable::find() will only ever return 1 item, the first item that it finds or nil.  Use Enumerable::select() or find_all() to return an array of items that it finds.

Answer (score -2):

If you use Rails Active Record as ORM and your Model named Product (only for example), 
you can use something like this:

```
def findID(serviceCode)
  Product.select(:id).where(serviceCode: serviceCode).first 
end
```

If you have plain SQL Query in plain ruby class (not recommended), you should change this query to get only the id, as Luiggi mentioned. But aware of SQL Injections if your serviceCode coming from external Requests.

Comment: this is not part of a  rails app